# encrypted (luks) partition had some damage - any chance?

Tags: linux, lvm, encryption, luks

I was trying to run Debian installer on top of an already luks-encrypted partition (I tried to do use cryptsetup in the console).

I don't remember ever saying "yes, destroy" data, but what I see now, is that encrypted turned into a PV (LVM).

Do I have any chance to restore the original?

I don't know the PV format vs the encrypted partition, so wondering if maybe no real damage was done, or if there is way to partially restore anything.

Comment: Consider it toast. Just restore from backup.

Answer (score 3):

Debian still hasn't fixed this bug? I lost data to this *five years ago*.

Yes, it's a bug. No, it isn't fixed. Yes, you're going to have to restore from backups, and I hope to Gawd you actually have them.

Comment: Thanks! What kind of bug are you referring to- one with the installer? Great, so it wasn't necessarily my fault (I was really trying to be careful).. except that I didn't have a backup:)  however the setup was quite new, the only "valuable" thing was some wifi setup, and Windows vM, set up by my IT which I don't want to bother with this.

Comment: Yes, it's a debian-installer bug. These days I confine Debian to virtual machines...

Comment: Could you describe the actual bug? a link would be even better :)

Comment: If it's a bug, there should be a BTS ticket number for it.